# Can't trigger 5V,10A relay using the output from a ESP8266 node MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, relay, esp8266

I'm currently working on a project where I turn off the ac appliances when the input signals of the relay get high. I'm using a 5V 10A relay and ESP8266 node MCU. But the problem is controller is unable to switch the relay. What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Find something that the controller can switch, which is capable of switching the relay. For example, a transistor. There are lotl of example circuits for this.

Comment: Hope you didn't fry that pin...

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to look for the datasheet of your relay and examine not only the recommended coil voltage but the current required to actuate the relay.

Most microcontroller modules can only source/sink a limited amount of current on their digital I/O lines (usually on the order of tens of milliamps). Relays can sometimes require over 100mA of current on their coils to remain "ON".

In order to do this, look into using an NPN transistor as a common emitter switch. Your micro controller can easily saturate and "turn on" a transistor such as the 2n3904 transistor which is capable of switching loads on the order of a few hundred milliamps. You'll need a resistor between your microcontroller's pin and the base of the transistor. Again, many available schematics and how-to's can be found online. A simple 1K ohm resistor is suitable for limiting current to the base of the 2n3904 when using 5V logic.

Be sure to also look into adding a "flyback diode" across the terminals of the relay's coil to prevent high voltage transients during switching on/off which can damage the transistor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a relay module?  If yes, check the specifications if it is high level trigger or low level trigger relay module.

I recently faced similar problem and learned that my relay module was of a high level trigger type. Now it’s easy when you are using low level input trigger relay module because all an MCU GPIO has to do is send digital signal of zero.

However, in high level trigger case, MCU is required to send the input voltage specified on the relay. In my case it was 3V to switch the relay from NC to NO and the GPIO on the MCU was giving out 2.6V for digital HIGH state.

I resolved this by building an external switch circuit using BC547 NPN transistor and a pair of resistors.  If interested to know more about this circuit, feel free to ask. It’s not a rocket science.

Hope this helps.